# Find value of dynamically added textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have generated some questions from a dataset  with textboxes next to them in a dynamically generated html table. I have 5 questions and 5 textboxes.
So, i need to get back the values of some textboxes.

I am looping through the dataset and adding a series of questions with textboxes next to them. However, do i need to generate some unique ID to each textbox?

```
private void GenerateTable(int colsCount, int rowsCount, DataSet ds, DataSet ds2)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        List<TableRow> tableRowList = new List<TableRow>();
        List<TableCell> tableCellList = new List<TableCell>();
        List<Control> controlsList = new List<Control>();

        foreach (DataTable dataTable in ds.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
                TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();
                TableCell tableCell2 = new TableCell();
                TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
                //textbox.ID = "TextBoxID";

                TableRow tableRow2 = new TableRow();
                TableCell tableCel2 = new TableCell();

                tableCell.Text = dataRow["QUESTIONTEXT"].ToString();


                if (dataRow["TYPEID"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    tableCell2.Controls.Add(textbox);
                    controlsList.Add(textbox);
                }


                tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);
                tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell2);
                myTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);

                tableRowList.Add(tableRow);
                tableCellList.Add(tableCell);
                tableCellList.Add(tableCell2);

                counter++;
            }
        }

        //TextBox tb = myTable.FindControl(TextBoxID) as TextBox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to generate some unique ID to each textbox?

Yes... id must be unique. a page with more than one element with the same id is **invaliid**

[spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-id):

> **id=name [CS]**
> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

But if you are not using the `id` at all you can just not assign id at all...

Comment: The only way i can think of doing it is to use a counter and add that to the unique ID name?

Comment: If i dont assign an ID how could i access it? I added to a list List<Control> controlsList = new List<Control>(); controlsList.Add(textbox);  so, now i have the indexes.

Comment: @icelated. Give it `id` if you need to, I only wrote not if you don't need the id you can forget about it. (There are folks who think you must assign an `id` to `each` element, which is not true.)